# SQL Server Pivot with grand total?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

I am able to pivot dymaically a tale with my parties from a table, the code below works fine and there's not problem below.

```
SELECT @PartiesNames +=  QUOTENAME(LTRIM(RTRIM([Party]))) + ',' 
        FROM table1 WHERE [Party] <> ''
        GROUP BY [Party]

SET @PartiesNames = LEFT(@PartiesNames, LEN(@PartiesNames) - 1)


SET @SQL =
    '
     SELECT * 
     FROM (SELECT 
                  table1.[Party]
                 ,table1.[Accounts]
                 ,[Amount] = FORMAT(SUM(table1.[Amount]),''N0'')
                 FROM  table1

                     GROUP BY table1.[Party]
                    ,table1.[Accounts]
                    ) AS BaseData

    PIVOT(
        MAX(BaseData.[Amount])
        FOR BaseData.[Party]
        IN(' + @PartiesNames + '     
        )
    ) AS PivotTable
    ' 

    EXEC( @SQL)
```

And I get a normal pivot table but my question, how can I adjust this code to get a new row or/and column with the total? I've been following this article on how to do it but it's qiute tricky to follow: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/232181/SQL-Pivot-with-Grand-Total-Column-and-Row

I am open to new solutions on how to solve this problem. I believe one reason why this is tricky to solve is because resources online are not very well explained and it does get tricky very fast, anyway I appreciate the support and suggestions.

Comment: Use `SUM` and `GROUP BY` or  `GROUP BY ROLLUP(<collumn>)` if you want it in a different row, like for sub-totals... or `GROUP BY CUBE(<column>,<column2>) ` or even `GROUPING SETS`. Depends on what you want.

Comment: I've used group by before but in a query like this, how would I do it? I'm quite unsure since I'm using the PIVOT function @scsimon

Answer (score 0):

If interested in a Helper Function.

This Table-Valued Function returns the `Count,Sum,Min,Max,Avg and STDev` of virtually any row.

All you have to do is add a `CROSS APPLY` after your `PIVOT`.

I should add that you must "**EXCLUDE**" any numeric column that you **DON'T** want in the  aggregates

**Example**

```
Declare @T1 Table ([Branch] varchar(50),[Item] varchar(50),[Sales] int)
Insert Into @T1 Values 
 ('23','Apples',25)
,('23','Coffee',56)
,('23','Bread',22)
,('14','Apples',56)
,('14','Coffee',65)
,('14','Bread',null)


Select Pvt.*
      ,Ttl.*
 From  @T1
 Pivot ( max(Sales) for Item in ([Apples],[Coffee],[Bread]) ) Pvt
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Stat-Row-Agg]('Branch,OtherColumsToExclude',(Select Pvt.* for XML Raw)) Ttl
```

**Returns**

```
/----     From Pivot    ----\  /----          From CROSS APPLY          ----\  

Branch  Apples  Coffee  Bread   RetCnt  RetSum  RetMin  RetMax  RetAvg  RetStd
14      56      65      NULL    2       121     56      65      60.5    6.3639
23      25      56      22      3       103     22      56      34.33   18.8237
```

**The TVF If Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Stat-Row-Agg](@Exclude varchar(500),@XML xml)
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetCnt = count(value) 
          ,RetSum = Sum(Value)
          ,RetMin = Min(Value)
          ,RetMax = Max(Value)
          ,RetAvg = Avg(Value)
          ,RetStd = Stdev(Value)
    From  (
            Select Item  = xAttr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                  ,Value = try_convert(float,xAttr.value('.','varchar(max)'))
             From  @XML.nodes('//@*') x(xAttr)
          ) S
    Where charindex(','+S.Item+',',','+@Exclude+',')=0
);
```